# Magento 2.2. with Varnish, Contact form not working

Tags: magento2.2, contact-us, contact-form

I am trying to test the contact form, but varnish is giving me 503 errors every time I am trying to submit the form. However, I don't think varnish is the issue here.

I am calling the form using the below `cms-code`:

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: varnish is not the problem, you have php error, check your logs